# nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type InwardRegister

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I receive the following error:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type InwardRegister

This is my code:

```java
@Repository
public interface InwardRegisterRepository extends ReactiveSortingRepository<InwardRegister,Long> {

    @AllowFiltering
    Flux<InwardRegister> findByDateTime(Date dateTime);

    @AllowFiltering
    Flux<InwardRegister> findBySenderOrderById(String sender);
}

@Service
public class InwardRegisterService {

    @Autowired
    InwardRegisterRepository inwardRegisterRepository;

    public Mono<InwardRegister> create(InwardRegister inwardRegisterRecord) {
        return inwardRegisterRepository.save(inwardRegisterRecord);
    }

    public Mono<InwardRegister> read(Long id){
        return inwardRegisterRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Flux<InwardRegister> readAll(){
        return inwardRegisterRepository.findAll(Sort.by("ASI","id"));
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Error Looks like your bean InwardRegister.class does not contain  @Id javax.persistence annotation for please provide Entity class details to check further..